# Google Analytics within amp-iframe doesn't appear to work

Tags: google-analytics, amp-html

I have an AMP page, using `amp-analytics`. It works great, and captures outgoing events and pageviews into Google Analytics correctly. ([Here](https://podnews.net/podcast/668413144))

I have a non-AMP media player. It contains  `analytics.gs`. When called normally - i.e. not in a frame - it works great, and captures pageviews and player activity. ([Here](https://podnews.net/podcast/player/668413144))

However, when you load the media player within the AMP page, as an `amp-iframe` with `sandbox="allow-scripts allow-top-navigation"`, the Google Analytics events do not load. It plays the audio fine, but doesn't appear to make any calls to Google Analytics other than the initial `analytics.js`. I don't see any error messages in the console.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of fiddling...

1. [Download the Google Analytics debugger Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna). This helps understand what's going on.
2. While the player itself worked fine, Google Analytics, since it asks to see a cookie, needs `allow-same-origin` to be added to the amp-iframe call. And, slightly unintuitively, that means that this page does not allow an iframe to be included from the same origin.

Once I'd understood the above, I managed - I think - to get it working.